# Error: Call to undefined function in inc file

Tags: 7

I searched for an explanation to this issue but didn't find anything. I have other sites where this is working but not in this one.

So, my module info file (draws.module):

```
name = draws
description = Draws custom module
package = Draws Modules
core = 7.x

files[] = draws.fixturesSavings.inc
```

In my draws.module I have this function (lines 289 to 231):

```
function saveToDatabase($response) {
    fixtures_saveToDatabase($response);
}
```

And then in the same folder of my draws.module I have the inc file (draws.fixturesSaving.inc):

```
<?php
function fixtures_saveToDatabase($response) {
```

And when I call function `saveToDatabase`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Call to undefined function fixtures_saveToDatabase() in saveToDatabase() (line 290 of /home/.../sites/all/modules/custom/draws/draws.module).
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **files (Optional)**
>
> Drupal supports a dynamic-loading code registry. To support it, all
> modules must declare any code files containing class or interface
> declarations in the .info file, like so:
>
> ```
> name = Really Neat Widget
> ...
> files[] = tests/example.test
> ```
>
> When a module is enabled, Drupal will rescan all declared files and
> **index all the classes and interfaces** that it finds. Classes will be loaded automatically by PHP when they are first accessed.
>
> Currently this mechanism does not natively support namespaced classes.
>
> <sub>Source: [Writing module .info files (Drupal 7.x)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-module-info-files-drupal-7x#files)</sub>

This approach only works with Object Oriented PHP. You would have to create a class.

If you want to keep with your current approach, add this to the top of the draws.module file after the `<?php` open tag.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'draws', 'draws.fixturesSavings');
```

Comment: HI @No Sssweat, thanks again for your support. Your suggestion to use module_load_include was the first one I used but it also gives the same error. That's why I tried to use the info file approach. This is very strange because it alwasys worked before.

Comment: @zephirus is draws.fixturesSaving.inc located in the module's root/main folder? or do you have it inside a sub folder?

Comment: the files are all on the same folder. sites/all/modules/custom/draws/

Comment: Just for testing purposes, if you copy the code in .inc and paste it in .module, does it work then?

Comment: In that case it works without any issues. I want to try to change to OO but I really want to understand what is happening here because it's very strange.

Comment: @zephirus I recreated your module, [working example](https://github.com/no-sssweat/draws/tree/master)

Comment: There is no difference in that example from what I already had. You commented that could be something related with the naming of the file right?

Comment: @zephirus sorry I was wrong, was my local site not clearing caches properly. Maybe the same issue you have? re-start your local dev? If still nothing, download and install my module. You should see a "Hello World" message.

Comment: I have this in a shared host. Already tried everything, clearing the cache, etc. Nothing works. I have the exact same code as you.

Comment: Install my module just to make sure. You could also go into the db and truncate all the cache tables in case for some reason they're not clearing. Otherwise, do a fresh drupal install with fresh core files somewhere and try your module there. Could be due to custom/contrib/ or altered D7 core code.

Comment: Damn, I have a typo in the inc filename. Even in this post I have that typo and it was not noticable at first glance. How did I not noticed this? Well, I appologize for the time you spent on this and again, I really appreciate your help. Btw, I will still try to change my module to use OO.

Comment: @zephirus heh, I didn't notice the extra "s" on the inc file name. I just took your `files[] =` value. Well glad the mystery is solved.